# Android: default icon for "more" in GridView or ListView

Tags: android, listview, gridview, icons, contextmenu

When you use the ActionBar, you will get the overflow icon automatically if you got menu items that are not shown as an icon.

[image: ActionBar Overflow]

In some apps you see a similar icon in the items of GridViews or ListViews indicating that there's more info when you click those items or that you get a PopupMenu if you click on the icon.

Do you know which icon this is? I could not find it in the icon-package provided by Google.

[image: ContextMenu indicator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `ic_action_overflow`.

Download `Action Bar Icon Pack` from [here](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html), scroll down a bit you will see `Action Bar Icon Pack`

After downloading extract the zip. Then `Core_Icons` --> `unstyled` --> `mdpi` there you will find `ic_action_overflow`

You can find it in `Action Bar Icons` --> `holo_dark` --> `01_core_overflow` also.

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: I knew that icon already. But that's not the same that is used in Play store. The one in Play store has rounded dots. But anyway, yeah I used the overflow-icon now.